# How the runtime knows which class contain the Main method in C# application?

Tags: c#, program-entry-point

I know that for Console/Windows application in C#, "Main" method is entry point to run the application.

If we have hundreds of classes in our application, how the runtime will detect which class contains the "Main" method to run the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler looks for

`static void Main(string[])`

or

`static int Main(string[])`

to determine the entry point. `Main()` may also be declared without the `string[]` argument. You only need to specifically set the project setting if you have multiple classes with `Main()` functions.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28VS.90%29.aspx) MSDN's detailed answer for you.

Comment: I have seen the mentioned URL, but it saying when there are multiple entry points. If I have only one entry point, how the runtime will detect which class contain the Main method? Will it search for all the classes (even I have 1000 classes)?

Comment: Yes, the compiler does that anyway - it has to build a symbol table of all symbols in your project to compile it and build the output binary. Finding the Main() method in the table is then a trivial problem for the compiler (searching through even thousands of classes is very fast since the compiler already prepared much of the data by that time).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Any other useful link(apart from the MSDN link) which describing your answer will be useful.

Comment: @Syed: well, there isn't much else to add. MSDN is pretty accurate in explaining what happens; when you have only a single `Main()` in your project is simply a special case of the more general explanation: in that case the compiler can simply infer that you want that `Main()` to be the entry point. If you have more than one, the project setting must be used to tell the compiler which one to pick.

Answer (score 2):

Entry Point can be configured in Project Settings.

Comment: It _must_ be configured if there are multiple entry points otherwise the project will not compile.

Comment: @AustinSalonen Thanks for your comment, if I have only one Main method?

Comment: It likely does a search for a `static void Main`.

Comment: [citation required], a screenshot will do nicely.